# django south migration issue

Tags: python, django, migration, django-south

i am really stuck here. i have a model, where i am migrating well untill now. but today i added new field, then i did `schemamigration app --auto`, then it found the newly added field, but when i ran `migrate app`, it says, the field `newfield` doesnot exist. i dont understand why. i uncommented and tried to schemamigration and migrate again, it is spitting out the same error now. what did i wrong and what should i do now? i want to have a fixed steps for such cases :(

thanks for help

edit:

```
class User(models.Model):
  registerdate = models.CharField(max_length=400,default='')
  vorname = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
  nachname = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
  plz = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='')  <------------- this field i added
  land = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
```

the error says:

`the following sql statement failed: ALTER TABLE home_user DROP COLUMN plz CASCADE;`

but now, i have this field uncommented and if i try to migrate, it says: column `PLZ` of Relation `USER` does not exist. why is this? :(

Comment: can you add the change (diff) you did to your model here? Can you do the same with the error you are getting (exact trace)? It seem you did the right thing so it would be helpful to have this information in order to help you...

Comment: @catherine, i did, but the same error is coming.

Comment: You would probably get more help if you post the traceback, relevant parts of the migration files. Also, what did you uncomment?!

Comment: @catherine, oh, i see that my newly added column doesnot really exist in db. why is this?

Comment: @catherine, no i didnot delete. what i did is: added field, did schemamigration app --auto, then migrate app. is it wrong?

Comment: Is your database for User model have existing information?

Comment: What did you comment?

Comment: @catherine, no, user doesnot have information yet. can i somehow go back to first state where i didnot have the newly added field?

Comment: @Thomasorozco, i commented ``plz`` and uncommented again to see what happens. but there is still no such column in my db.

Comment: Try this one: `plz = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)`. Delete the latest schema, create schema then migrate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i uncommented and tried to schemamigration and migrate again, it is
>   spitting out the same error now.

Did you delete the migration you created after adding the new field? If not, then running migrate will keep trying to run this migration. Since you say it failed to run the first time, it will always keep failing to run unless it's corrected or deleted.

If that first migration really did fail to run, you could try deleting it (and any subsequent migrations you may have created), then recreating it.

Before trying that, though, it would be helpful for you to post more complete tracebacks of the errors you get when you run migrate. You may have a mismatch between what south thinks the state of your database is and what it actually is, but it's hard to say for sure without more information.